# Where does MongoDB store index data?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, installation, storage

I want to create a separate disk to store MongoDB Database. But I realized that, databases also have indexes. So I might need to have disk size more than the size of records.

The question is where does mongo db stores it's index data.
In config file we only mention path of logs and db folder.

Comment: It is stored in the db folder, along with the collections themselves.

Answer (score 4):

> The question is where does mongo db stores it's index data. In config
> file we only mention path of logs and db folder.

The index data is stored along with the collection data in the `data` directory of the MongoDB Server installation. You can also specify the data directory using the [--dbpath](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/index.html#cmdoption-mongod-dbpath) storage option when you start the [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/).

The files are stored with names like the following, for example:

```
collection-2-3986418375741882655.wt 
index-1-221874391618151955.wt
```

The first one is a collection data file and the second one is an index data file. For each collection and index, one file for each is created respectively. So, if there are 3 collections and 5 indexes there will be 8 files (the data directory has other files too).

There is also a [--directoryperdb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/index.html#cmdoption-mongod-directoryperdb) option, which when specified:

> Uses a separate directory to store data for each database. The
> directories are under the --dbpath directory, and each subdirectory
> name corresponds to the database name.

**[EDIT Update]: Indexes can be stored in separate directory**

[MongoDB Configuration File Options - storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.directoryForIndexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/configuration-options/#storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.directoryForIndexes)

> When `storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.directoryForIndexes` is true,
> `mongod` stores indexes and collections in *separate* subdirectories
> under the data (i.e. storage.dbPath) directory. Specifically, `mongod`
> stores the indexes in a subdirectory named `index` and the collection
> data in a subdirectory named `collection`.