# Can I configure a specific path for MongoDB Indexes?

Tags: database, mongodb, ubuntu, indexing, storage

I have two disks in my Ubuntu server (HDD and SSD). My MongoDB database is located at the HDD disk. All the find complex queries are very slow. Moving the database to the SSD made it super fast. However, the cost is high. I'm wondering if we can create a directory for the database indexes on the SSD disk and a database directory on the HDD one?

Comment: Some info about configuring the index storage: [Where does MongoDB store index data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058063/where-does-mongodb-store-index-data/66058668#66058668).

Comment: Also see [Query Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/).

Comment: I applied everything in the both links with no improvement @prasad_

Comment: Then the problem must be some other reason. Do you have specific queries which are performing slow? Did you run explain() on those queries (and what do you see in the query plan)? What is your deployment (is it a standalone, a cluster) and its version?