# Mongodb on the cloud

Tags: mongodb, cloud, replicaset, volumes

I'm preparing my production environment on the Hetzner cloud, but I have some doubts (I'm more a developer than a devops).

I will get 3 servers for the replicaset with 8 core, 32 Gb ram and 240 gb ssd. I'm a bit worried about the size of the ssd the server comes with and Hetzner has the possibility to create volumes to be attached to the servers. Since mongodb uses a single folder for the db data, I was wondering how can I use the 240 gb that comes with the server in combination with external volumes. At the beginning I can use the 240 gb, but then I will have to move the data folder to a volume when it reaches capacity. Im fine with this, but it looks to me that when I will move to volumes, this 240gb will not be used anymore (yes I can use them to save the mongo journaling as they suggest to store it in a separate partition).

So, my noob question is, how can I use both the disk that comes with the server and the external volumes?

Thank you

Comment: In general, there are _options_ for MongoDB to store indexes and data in different directories. Also, there is an option to store each database in a different directory. I think one can point these directories to individual disks. Some info at: [Where does MongoDB store index data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058063/where-does-mongodb-store-index-data)

Comment: Is an LVM expandable volume an option?

Comment: I saw there is the possiblity to have one db per folder, but for the moment I have a unique db. Not sure about LVM, but I think yes.

Comment: You can also use RAID 0 and stripe the disks.

Comment: Yuri, is that RAID10 on the 240gb and the mounted volume? if that's the case, does the two mounts need to have same space?

Comment: What is your conclusion? Have you put something on Hetzner volumes? Is speed sufficient?