# Should I follow the divide & conquer principle with respect to MongoDB storage?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, database-design, cluster-computing

My app will store a lot of data, currently all the data is in one relational table, if in future I'm planning to buy extra GB of memory, is there any need now to divide the storage between serveral relationaltables/ or even between several clusters? Is one relational table able to serve big amount of data?
I currently store everything here:

```
 mongoose.connect(
`mongodb+srv://{myusername}:${process.env.MONGOPASS}@cluster0.{id ont know if i can share this hash here or now}.mongodb.net/sometests? 
 retryWrites=true&w=majority
  `,
    {
       useNewUrlParser: true,
       useCreateIndex: true,
       useUnifiedTopology: true,
       useFindAndModify: true,
    }
 );
```

Comment: What do you mean, "relational"?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, In this case whne saying relational table I mean subtitle "sometests" whne connecting to db

Comment: You can store each database and its indexes in different folders /drives via configuration; see this SO post for details: [Where does MongoDB store index data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66058063/where-does-mongodb-store-index-data/66058668#66058668).

Comment: @prasad_, thank you, I'll have a look at the article